# How to get the inner type of a generic class

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following code:

```
interface Outer<T = any> {
    name: string;
    body: T;
}

interface MyClass<T extends Outer> {
    myFunction2: typeof myFunction2;
};

class MyClass<T extends Outer> {
    data: T;

    myFunction1() {
        return this.data.body;
    }

}

MyClass.prototype.myFunction2 = myFunction2;

function myFunction2<T extends MyClass<Outer<R>>, R>(this: T): R {
    return this.data.body;
}
```

If I now create an instance of the class and tries to access the body-property directly it works as expected:

```
let myClass = new MyClass<Outer<number>>();
const direct = myClass.data.body; // number
```

But if I try to access the property by a function, I can't get it to work.

```
const f1 = myClass.myFunction1(); // is 'any' but expecting 'number'  
const f2 = myClass.myFunction2(); // is '{}' but expecting 'number'
```

How can I make typescript aware about the inner type (the type of body in this example)? I know it's possible to give typescript more information like:

```
const f2 = myClass.myFunction2<MyClass<Outer<number>>, number>(); // number
```

But that is very verbose and I lose some type safety.

Question:
Can I rewrite MyClass somehow to make typescript aware of the return value of myFunction1 and myFunction2? I'm mostly interested in how to solve it for myFunction2 (extending the prototype) but function1 is also interesting.

[The code in typescript playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Outer%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction2%3A%20typeof%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AMyClass.prototype.myFunction2%20%3D%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction2%3CT%20extends%20MyClass%3COuter%3CR%3E%3E%2C%20R%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myClass%20%3D%20new%20MyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20direct%20%3D%20myClass.data.body%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction1()%3B%20%2F%2F%20any%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aconst%20f3%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2%3CMyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E%2C%20number%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out the T['key'] syntax which can be used to get an inner type:

```
interface Outer<T = any> {
    name: string;
    body: T;
}

interface MyClass<T extends Outer> {
    myFunction2: typeof myFunction2;
};

class MyClass<T extends Outer> {
    data: T;

    myFunction1(): T['body'] {
        return this.data.body;
    }

}

MyClass.prototype.myFunction2 = myFunction2;

function myFunction2<T extends Outer>(this: MyClass<T>): T['body'] {
    return this.data.body;
}
```

So now I can get the "inner" type

```
let myClass = new MyClass<Outer<number>>();
const direct = myClass.data.body; // number
const f1 = myClass.myFunction1(); // number
const f2 = myClass.myFunction2(); // number
```

Edit: [Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Outer%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction2%3A%20typeof%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AMyClass.prototype.myFunction2%20%3D%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction2%3CT%20extends%20MyClass%3COuter%3CR%3E%3E%2C%20R%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myClass%20%3D%20new%20MyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20direct%20%3D%20myClass.data.body%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction1()%3B%20%2F%2F%20any%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aconst%20f3%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2%3CMyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E%2C%20number%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0A%0D%0A#src=interface%20Outer%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction2%3A%20typeof%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction1()%3A%20T%5B'body'%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AMyClass.prototype.myFunction2%20%3D%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction2%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E(this%3A%20MyClass%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%5B'body'%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myClass%20%3D%20new%20MyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20direct%20%3D%20myClass.data.body%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction1()%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2()%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, sadly, TypeScript does not infer deeper properties in a generic type. It also eagerly resolve type variable, so `myFunction1` is typed as if `T` is `Outer`. Thus its return value is `any`. You need to explicitly type the `body` property in `data`.

```
interface Outer<T = any> {
    name: string;
    body: T;
}

class MyClass<T> {
    data: Outer<T>;
    myFunction2: typeof myFunction2;

    myFunction1() {
        return this.data.body;
    }

}

MyClass.prototype.myFunction2 = myFunction2;

function myFunction2<T extends MyClass<R>, R>(this: T): R {
    return this.data.body;
}

let myClass = new MyClass<number>();
const direct = myClass.data.body; // number
const f1 = myClass.myFunction1(); // now is number
const f2 = myClass.myFunction2(); // still {}, due to inference constraint
const f3 = myClass.myFunction2<MyClass<number>, number>(); // number
```

[Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Outer%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction2%3A%20typeof%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Outer%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AMyClass.prototype.myFunction2%20%3D%20myFunction2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction2%3CT%20extends%20MyClass%3COuter%3CR%3E%3E%2C%20R%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.data.body%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myClass%20%3D%20new%20MyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20direct%20%3D%20myClass.data.body%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction1()%3B%20%2F%2F%20any%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aconst%20f3%20%3D%20myClass.myFunction2%3CMyClass%3COuter%3Cnumber%3E%3E%2C%20number%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%0D%0A%0D%0A)